# RecyclerView for users is empty

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to show the users from their primary key in a RecyclerView using Firebase Realtime Database but everytime I try the RecyclerView is empty. I tried o lots of tutorials but nothing seems to help
Here's how my databse looks:

[image: 1]

This is the class where i used the RecyclerView

```
public class UsersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView userslist;
    private DatabaseReference ref;
    private List<Users> mUsers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_users );
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ("users");

        userslist = (RecyclerView) findViewById ( R.id.users_list );


        userslist.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager ( this ) );
       mUsers=new ArrayList<> (  );
       readUsers ();

ref.addValueEventListener ( new ValueEventListener () {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren ()){
            Users users=dataSnapshot.getValue (Users.class);
            mUsers.add ( users );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled (@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
} );
    }

    public void readUsers(){
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance ().getCurrentUser ();
        DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ("users");
        reference.addValueEventListener ( new ValueEventListener () {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {




            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled (@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        } );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart () {
        super.onStart ();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Users> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users> ()
                .setQuery ( ref, Users.class )
                .build ();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, FindFriendViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, FindFriendViewHolder> ( options ) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder (@NonNull FindFriendViewHolder findFriendViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Users users) {
                findFriendViewHolder.userName.setText ( users.getName () );

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public FindFriendViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from ( parent.getContext () ).inflate ( R.layout.users_template, parent, false );
                FindFriendViewHolder viewHolder = new FindFriendViewHolder ( view );
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };
        userslist.setAdapter ( adapter );
       adapter.startListening ();
    }

    public static class FindFriendViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView userName;
        ImageView profileImage;

        public FindFriendViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView) {
            super ( itemView );
            userName = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.username1 );
            profileImage = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.profilepicture );

        }


    }
}
```

The adapter for users name

```
public class Users {
    public String name;
    public Users(){}
    public Users(String name){
    this.name=name;}
    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

I expect that the RecyclerView to be populated with all the users after their primary key.

Comment: 1) Your `readUsers` seems useless, since the listener is not doing anything with the data it receives. Is this relevant to the problem? If not, why are you sharing that code with us? 2) You seem to both be using your own listener to read the users, and using a FirebaseUI adapter (which does that for you). Which of the two are you asking about? Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it really makes a difference in how like you are to get help.

Comment: I forgot to delete readusers. I'm trying with the FirebaseRecyclerOptions. I'll delete the readusers. What changes can I do to display the users in my database after I delete readUsers? Sorry for my mistake.I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this is the example for firebase realtime database with recyclerview](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md)